# Building an XML file from an XSD using Python

Tags: python, xml, xsd, python-xmlschema

can I build an XML file from XSD using Python?
I found that xmlschema package expected to do this but failed to found a simple working example...

For example, using the code below its not working for me:

```
xs = xmlschema.XMLSchema('tests/test_cases/examples/collection/collection.xsd')
pprint(xs.to_dict('tests/test_cases/examples/collection/collection.xml'))
```

another option is using the [generateDS](https://pypi.org/project/generateDS/) package.

Comment: Seems unlikely in the general case - it's a bit like saying "could you draw me a map of roads and rivers (the XML file) if all roads are coloured red and rivers blue (the schema)?"

Comment: Don't tell us that something doesn't work, tell us how it fails. We can't diagnose a problem without knowing the symptoms.

Comment: It would also be useful to know _why_ you want to do this.

Comment: I get an error: failed with: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tests/test_cases/examples/collection/collection.xml' .                                               from https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html I understand its expected to create the xml itself....                                                                          by the way I found Pycharm do this genration xsd->xml                                        pycharm: xsd-> xml but I need the code for doing this...
Pycahrm--> Tools | XML Actions | Generate XML Document from XSD Schema

Comment: There is also online link for this: http://xsd2xml.com/ (its get some example xml can created from this xsd....)